# How to properly retrieve text from decoded json PHP

Tags: php, json

Im trying to get an image link from a JSON file which I can retrieve by a link [like this](https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=15d2ea6d0dc1d476efbca3eba2b9bbfb&query=Raiders%25of%25the%25lost%25ark) the problem I am having is extracting the correct data. I want to get the field poster_path which is inside the results array however my attempts have been unsuccessful. Currently this is my code -

```
$json = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=15d2ea6d0dc1d476efbca3eba2b9bbfb&query='.$title;
$json = preg_replace('/\s+/', '%', $json);
$json = file_get_contents($json);
$obj = json_decode($json);
echo $obj->results[0]['poster_path'];
//Have also tried
//echo $obj->results[0]->poster_path;
```

It works if I only try to reach the, for example total_pages data however im unable to access the results array.

EDIT - Turns out the results array doesn't actually pick up its contents from the link, the JSON is left like this - {"page":1,"total_results":0,"total_pages":1,"results":[]}

Comment: Seems `$obj->results[0]` is also a JSON.

Comment: @MilanChheda think you could write an answer?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how that particular API works but did you just publish your API key? You might want to hide it and display the request response in the question instead :)

Comment: It's not mine it came from another site, i'm not too worried about it its just a proof of concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use object syntax to access the property instead:

```
$obj->results[0]->poster_path
```

will return the data you want.

You also have a problem with your url-encoding. Your approach using `preg_replace` is wrong (should be %20 not just %) but it's also naive because it doesn't account for other possible encoding issues in the input. PHP has a built-in function `urlencode` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) which is designed to take care of this kind of thing for you.

And lastly you have an odd variable naming - the use of "$json" for your url string doesn't make any sense, and also you already use that name further down for the response from the remote server, which makes a lot more sense. Variables with different purposes should be named according to their purpose and also not conflict / overwrite each other. This will make your code more maintainable ingeneral.

Here's a better version of your code:

```
$url = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=15d2ea6d0dc1d476efbca3eba2b9bbfb&query='.urlencode($title);
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$obj = json_decode($json);
echo $obj->results[0]->poster_path;
```

Comment: what error did you get? I tried it and it's fine. See this runnable example: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/i5bj-xm9u . The only possible difference I can think of in your case might possibly be that $title is invalid, and you aren't getting the response you expected from the API. If the title has spaces, such as the example link you provided in the question, then please ensure you url-encode it before you append it to your base URL.

Comment: Yeah the online example worked however whenever I run it locally it give me an Undefined offset error as it leaves the results array empty

Comment: like I said, check what actual URL is being called (you can var_dump it before you call file_get_contents) and whether it's encoded properly. Run that in your browser too, to see what response is produced. Since that's the only difference between your code and mine, then that's almost certainly the problem. Your approach using preg_replace is naive (as well as wrongly implemented) and only caters for one possible encoding issue. Instead call urlencode (http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) on the whole URL string before calling file_get_contents.

Comment: Another minor readability point - calling your url string "$json" is really odd, because it's a URL string, not a JSON object. Calling the response $json makes more sense. But you're using the same variable for both. They are different, with different purposes. I have updated the answer with both of those points

Comment: Hey, sorry for trying to learn. It should be fairly obvious i'm new to PHP, Maybe next time I won't try at all? But yeah I changed that JSON thing.

Comment: Don't be sorry for learning, I was just trying to help. It's natural to make this kind of mistake. I wasn't trying to be rude, just pointing out the simple facts which I thought might be useful in future. I thought I did that quite neutrally but sorry if you took it personally. If it makes you feel better, I made a mistake in my code above and just had to correct the answer again :-) (urlencode should only need to be called on the title variable, not the whole base URL)

Comment: BTW in the spirit of learning, there are a lot of answers to the question, including your own. Normal convention on the site is to pick the one which was most useful to you (assuming it actually solves the problem) and mark it as the accepted answer (by clicking the tick next to it). You can pick your own answer if you think it's the best, that's quite common. Then future readers know what helped the most.

Answer (score 0):

```
$obj->results[0]->poster_path;
```

should work well. But some object has a null inside that attribute. E.g.:

```
{
  "vote_count": 0,
  "id": 479701,
  "video": false,
  "vote_average": 0,
  "title": "Test",
  "popularity": 4.92,
  "poster_path": null,
  "original_language": "en",
  "original_title": "Test",
  "genre_ids": [
    28
  ],
  "backdrop_path": null,
  "adult": false,
  "overview": "Testing the APIs",
  "release_date": "2017-10-05"
}
```

If you want to get array instead object, you shoul to set `true` as second parameter of `json_decode`:

```
$obj = json_decode($json, true);
```

Then you can get your data as:

```
echo $obj['results'][0]['poster_path'];
```

Comment: Im still getting this error - 
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/website/search.php on line 21,  Line 21 is the echo line

Comment: Are you shure that `file_get_contents` returns correct answer? Try to call `var_dump($json)` before you do `json_decode`. And look at an output.

Comment: Ahh you're right all its getting is this - string(57) "{"page":1,"total_results":0,"total_pages":1,"results":[]}"

Comment: Yeah your $obj['results'] may be empty. Check it with `if(!empty($obj['results']))`

Comment: Yeah the results array is empty, any idea why its not getting that part?

Comment: It's a normal behavior when no results for your request. Perhaps there is no movie with the name you requested.

Comment: Turns out the prag_replace was wrong it needed to be %20 instead of %.

Comment: Oh, you can use `urlencode` instead:

    `$url = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=15d2ea6d0dc1d476efbca3eba2b9bbfb&query=' . urlencode($title);`

Answer (score 0):

```
$json = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=15d2ea6d0dc1d476efbca3eba2b9bbfb&query=Raiders%25of%25the%25lost%25ark';
        $json = preg_replace('/\s+/', '%', $json);
        $json = file_get_contents($json);
        $obj = json_decode($json);
        $result = array();
        foreach($obj->results as $key=>$value)
        {
            $result[$value->id] = $value->poster_path;
        }
        echo $result;
```

i hope this is what you are searching for!!
if not please update what output are you expecting

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it wasn't an issue with the JSON but the prag_replace was replacing white spaces in the url with % instead of %20 this meant it couldn't find the result so it failed.